# How do I edit the output of my crosstab to show a percentage to the 2nd decimal point?

Tags: python, dataframe, formatting, percentage, crosstab

part of of my crosstab, I figured out how to re order the index but now I am stuck on how to format my crosstab output to show the data to the 2nd. decimal point.

I started with this code

```
pd.crosstab(data['One'],data['two'], margins=True).apply(lambda r: r/len(data)*100,axis = 1)
```

The out put looks like this

```
A          B         C       All
B    10.0000   40.0000   50.0000
C    40.0000   10.0000   50.0000
All  50.0000   50.0000   100.0000
```

but im looking for something like

```
A         B         C       All
B    10.00%    40.00%    50.00% 
C    40.00%    10.00%    50.00% 
All  50.00%    50.00%    100.00%
```

Any ideas on how to format my data?
Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}%'.format
```

Then if you display the dataframe it will have only two digits after the decimal point with % sign.

Answer (score 0):

your lambda is the main doing the main work in that line therefore i have done some changes

`pd.crosstab(data['One'],data['two'], margins=True).apply(lambda r:"{:.2f}".format((r/len(data)*100))+'%',axis = 1)`